# Symfony 5, Doctrine. Вывод данных в виде ассоциативного массива

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine2

Делаю запрос

`$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p', 'd')
            ->leftJoin(
                AudioBook::class,
                'd',
                'WITH',
                ' p.id = d.product')
            ;`

```
$res = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

И получаю примерно такую структуру данных

```
[0] => array(3) {       
    ["name"]=>string(9) "Brassicas"
    ["id"]=> int(13)
}
[1] =>
    array(3) {
    ["garden"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["id"]=> int(18)
    }
```

то есть я объединяю две таблицы  и получаю два массива где первый соответствует первой таблице, второй второй таблице.

Можно ли как-то вывести эти данные в виде ассоциативного массива? Что-то типа

```
[
 "firstEntity" => [],
"secondEntity => []
]
```

Comment: Ну так не надо `getArrayResult`, а просто `getResult`.

Comment: мне желательно именно getArrayResult использовать, с getArrayResult никак нельзя?

Comment: используйте `getResult` и оберните результаты в мапер, который из сущности вам создаст необходимый массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку Вы используете алиасы в select, то и возвращаются два элемнта массива. Если хотите получить ассоциативный массив, то указывайте выбираемые поля

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p.id as pId, p.name as pName, d.id as dId, d.garden as dGarden')
    ...
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

тогда у вас получится массив

```
[
    "pId" => ...
    "pName" => ...
    "dId" => ...
    "dGarden" => ...
]
```